# Text in Cell includes "&" character and stops code working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code that joins together a few cells from a spreadsheet and puts them into an email. My problem is that when a cell has the `&` character in it, the code stops working after the `&` has appeared.

`Msg = "Ref: " & Cells(ThisRow, 1) & vbCrLf & "Item: " & Cells(ThisRow, 2) & vbCrLf`

If for example `Cells(ThisRow, 1)` contains `&`, the following `Cells(ThisRow, 2)` doesn't get pulled in.

Can I get around this?

Comment: Is your email formatted as HTML? You could try replacing '&' with '&amp;' if that's the case (& is a special character in HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the & in the cell before you use the cell:

```
activecell = Replace(activecell, "&", "and")
```

or do the whole sheet at once:

```
cells.Replace What:="&", Replacement:="and"
```

Answer (score 0):

Store each cell's text as a string
This worked for me in Excel, writing the value to another cell.

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim resultString As String

str1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ThisRow, 1)
str2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ThisRow, 2)
resultString = str1 & " " & str2

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ThisRow, 3) = resultString
```